# Как исправить ошибку при вызове VKSdk.authorize()?

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь прикрутить к приложению VKSdk. При попытке вызова VKSdk.authorize(scope) получаю ошибку:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "vkauthorize://authorize" - error: "Не удалось завершить операцию. (OSStatus, ошибка -10814)"
```

Запускаю приложение в эмуляторе (Swift 3, iOS 10.0)

Выполненные действия:

1. Создал standalone-приложение Вконтакте.
2. Настроил в info.plist приложения URL-types по мануалу из Twitter. По вбитому в Safari урлу vkXXXXXXX:// приложение открывается.
3. Настроил в info.plist приложения

---

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>vk</string>
    <string>vk-share</string>
    <string>vkauthorize</string>
</array>
```

4. Добавил в AppDelegate метод:

---

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    VKSdk.processOpen(url, fromApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!)

    let sdkInstance = VKSdk.initialize(withAppId: "XXXXXXXX")
    sdkInstance!.register(self)
    sdkInstance!.uiDelegate = self

    let scope = ["friends", "email"]
    VKSdk.wakeUpSession(scope, complete: {(state: VKAuthorizationState, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if state == .authorized {
            NSLog("authorized")
        } else {
            VKSdk.authorize(scope)
        }
        return
    })


    return true
}
```

5. Запускаю приложение в эмуляторе. Перехожу в Safari, ввожу в адресной строке vkXXXXXXXX://. Открывается диалоговое окно с предложением открыть приложение. После подтверждения выполняется представленный выше код и в момент вызова VKSdk.authorize(scope) получаю озвученную вначале ошибку.

Comment: Что за ошибка-то?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Добавил текст ошибки.